# Matlab search for string in a text file and print the next line in a LOOP

Tags: matlab, file, text, import

I want to find a string `'Month'` in a text file that has numbers and other information e.g

> *My name is Dee
>
> *Month
>
> 2 3 4
>
> 3 6 8
>
> 4 87 9
>
> *Day
>
> 1, 4, 67,
>
> 2, 6, 98,
>
> 3, 55, 89,
>
> 4, 12, 34,
>
> *das
>
> *gfsd
>
> *gdfd
>
> *sdasd
>
> *end of file

and create an array of those numbers. Next, I want to search for next string, `'Day'`, and create an array of the corresponding numbers.

At the moment I am running a loop that searches all the characters twice and finds the numbers. This is making the program very slow. Can anyone please suggest a faster 
way to do it?

```
strToSearchFor = 'Month'; 
lengthStrToSearchFor = length(strToSearchFor); 
MonthArrayFlag =0;

for i=1:lengthAllFileChars
    fseek(fid9,i-1, 'bof');                                     
    tline = fscanf(fid9,'%c',lengthStrToSearchFor);
    if (strcmp(strToSearchFor,tline)==1)
        'FOUND IT';
        tline;
        for a = 1:lengthAllFileChars                        
            MonthNumber = fscanf(fid9, '%f,')';     
            if MonthArrayFlag == 0;
                MonthArray = zeros(1,4);                     
                MonthArray(1,:) =  nodeCoordinates;
                MonthArrayFlag = 1;
            else
                MonthArray = vertcat(MonthArray,MonthNumber);
            end
        end         
    end
end
```

This code is then repeated for `'DAY'`.

Comment: @M42 -guys, while this question may be rather vague, this question is clearly specific (I would argue almost tom much) in what it is asking. I think saying this question is not specific enough or reproducible does not make sense in this case. If you are going to close this question, at least do it for the right reasons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use textscan exactly as suggested by the other poster, this will (should?) return a cell array where everything that has a space in it is separated into its own cell.

Now instead of going through each cell, etc. etc. Do this instead:

```
monthInd=find(strcmp('Month',yourNewCellArray)) 
%Keep in mind this IS case sensitive

dayInd= same thing ^^^ for day

endOfDayInd = same thing, 
%hopefully you have some way of knowing when numbers stop?
```

then you can do:

```
monthVals=cell2mat(yourNewCellArray(monthInd+1:dayInd-1)) 
%pretty sure its () in this case rather than {}
```

Only caveat to this and the other posters method is values are now a vector instead of say a 3x3 matrix. If you don't need them  in a matrix, or can reshape your vector the matrix, you are good to go.

If not though, all hope is not lost! Substitute the '%s' in textscan for char(10) ..which is the new line char. Ideally your code won't need changing to find the month and day indices, but now each row of the numbers in between will be its own separate string.

This will probably need some tweaking, and probably a little bit of a priori knowledge if possible, but should give you some ideas at least :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply,     I dont have any information about how many rows are there in the Month Information and want to scan the whole file and create array for numbers under title Month and Another Array for 'Day'....If possible can you please provide clues about how the code will look like? Thank heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the function "textscan" ? You can probably read line by line of the textfile in one shot (textscan(fid, '%s')) and check for the keywords MONTH or DAY, if its a miss then its one of those number arrays in which you can turn its string into a matrix by the function "str2num". If you need help with the code I might be able to provide you with some rough code but not sure when.
The less you use functions that access the file the faster your program will run. That's where textscan comes in which reads everything and places it in one or more cell array(s).